# How to access source code files and list directories using GitLab API?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using GitLab and I completed setup as described in [Gitlab installation instructions](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md), I am now trying to access its RestFul API to perform tasks like create/delete Projects or Users(I am able to do this successfully).

I now have to list out all the directories within the master branch (or any other branch the project has) and want to access source code files listed in those directories(e.g. myproject->master->api, src->somefile.java etc), is it possible to do something like that using the existing Gitlab's API?

The whole list of API's that can be called are mentioned [here](http://api.gitlab.org/) and I was looking into [Project Snippets API](http://api.gitlab.org/project_snippets.html) and used this API `GET /projects/:id/snippets` to list all snippets but it returns an empty array, I do have files in my project but the result is empty.

I am assuming that project snippets refer to source code files or any other files within the project, please correct me if I am wrong, I am confused here as the authors of the Gitlab API failed to explain the terminology behind the usage of the word 'snippets'.

How can I access full directory structure and get files I need using the API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am assuming that project snippets refer to source code files or any other files within the project

No, you can see snippets in the GitLab demo project: [diaspora snippets](http://demo.gitlab.com/diaspora/diaspora/snippets).
They are in a separate tabs than the "Files" tab.
They would be the equivalent of [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Have a look at the [repository API](http://api.gitlab.org/repositories.html), like:

#### List repository tree

> Get a list of repository files and directories in a project.

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/tree
```

#### Raw blob content

> Get the raw file contents for a file.

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/blob
```

[astratto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268887/astratto) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3383328) that the new API (6.x) requires that a filepath is appended:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/blobs/:sha?filepath=:filepath
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, I tried that too before and I tried it now, I get 404 error when I call http://myserver/api/v3/projects/4/repository/tree?private_token=sometoken, any idea why?

Comment: yes, I tried both posting project id as parameter and directly embedding it in the url, but the result is same.

Comment: @ArifNadeem and you do set the right private token in order to authenticate yourself properly?

Comment: yes my private token is right, it seems when I try to access /projects/:id/repository/tree it fails with 404(please observe /tree in the url), but when I try to access /projects/4/repository/branches it succeeds.
May be the path tree is not found here, any idea?
Also when I try to access this API GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/blob, it asks for 'filepath' parameter, what should be the format of filepath? I tried username/reponame/filename but it fails with 404.