# How to get contents of a sub directory in a Gitlab repository using Gitlab API (with PHP curl)

Tags: php, api, curl, gitlab

I am trying to get a list of repository contents using Gitlab API from a repository subdirectory.

Because top level access is working fine, I'm assuming the issue is not authorization or general approach, but the URL and parameters being passed for the subdirectory. Or perhaps this is a documented but unimplemented feature of Gitlab API.

For example, using PHP and curl GET, the following URL works for top level list of files and folders:

The API doc says:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/tree
```

And this URL works ok with a curl GET function:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/USERNAME%2FPROJECTNAME/repository/tree
```

(the USERNAME%2FPROJECTNAME with %2F I found in another gitlab thread. This appears to be what the docs mean by ID)

For clarifcation, the snipppet of working code for top level list of contents is:

```
$url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/USERNAME%2FPROJECTNAME/repository/tree";
$ch = curl_init($url);
```

---

So for sub directory access, the API docs list paramters:

> **id** (required) - The ID of a project
>   **path** (optional) - The path inside repository. Used to get contend of subdirectories
>   **ref_name** (optional) - The name of a repository branch or tag or if not given the default branch

So based on this, I tried each of the following as the URL for curl_init command above:

```
$url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/USERNAME%2FPROJECTNAME/repository/tree?path=SUBDIRECTORY";
```

This returns an empty string. In case I was missing something, I also tried each of the following:

```
$params = array( 'path' => SUBDIRECTORY);

$url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/USERNAME%2FPROJECTNAME/repository/tree . "?" . http_build_query($params);

$url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/USERNAME%2FPROJECTNAME/repository/tree . "?" . urlencode(http_build_query($params));

$url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/USERNAME%2FPROJECTNAME/repository/tree . "%3F" . urlencode(http_build_query($params));
```

But all of these return an empty string from Gitlab API. Not an error, just empty string.

---

For reference, existing issues which did not help:

[How to get subfolders and files using gitlab api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952935/how-to-get-subfolders-and-files-using-gitlab-api)

[How to access source code files and list directories using GitLab API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063630/how-to-access-source-code-files-and-list-directories-using-gitlab-api)

Neither answer more than is available in current docs or give concrete examples of a working solution.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, problem solved by doing one or both of the following (I'm not sure which one solved it):

- Added SSH key
- Used Project ID rather than NAMESPACE/PROJECTNAME in the url.

Then with ?path=SUBDIRECTORY&ref_name=master on the URL (as in question), it worked.

Comment: 3k views and not one single upvote? Oh well